# Как в рантайме менять переменную окружения DISPLAY демона linux?

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5, x11

Демону нужно посылать команды нужному дисплею в рантайме. Для получения дисплея используется метод `Display* QX11Info::display()`. Но этот метод бесполезен, если не установлена переменная окружения процесса `DISPLAY`, а она при автостарте демона и не устанавливается.

Её можно менять только **до** создания экземпляра `QApplication` в `main()`, после qputenv (да и setenv()) игнорируют её смену.

Как в рантайме менять переменную окружения DISPLAY демона (написанного на qt) linux?

Comment: использовать [XOpenDisplay](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html) напрямую. а не через Qt'шные обёртки, не?

Comment: @Fat-Zer Display* disp = ::XOpenDisplay(":<num>"); при запуске из демона nullptr, а если из креатора, то работает. Хз почему

Comment: от какого пользователя работает демон?

Comment: @Fat-Zer от рута

Comment: я подозреваю, что в X залогинен кто-то другой, а по умолчанию он лочит все соединения от нетекущего пользовавателя... сделай сначала `xhost +local:` или `xhost +SI:localuser:root` (по вкусу)

Comment: @Fat-Zer подозрения оправданы, заработало. Оформите как ответ, и, если не сложно, пару слов о разграничении доступа с помощью xhost для рута. Чтоб не слетало после ребута.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для открытия конкретного дисплея по имени можно использовать напрямую [`XOpenDisplay (3)`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/display/opening.html) вместо Qt'шных обёрток.

Если демон запускается от другого пользователя (в т.ч. root) нежели того, что залогинен в X, то по умолчанию соединение с сервером ему будет запрещено. Для управления всей этой радостью есть утилита [`xhost`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xhost.1.html).

- Разрешить доступ всем локальным пользователям

  ```
  xhost +local:
  ```
- Разрешить доступ конкретному пользователю, в данном случае `root`

  ```
  xhost +SI:localuser:root
  ```

Нормального способа сделать эти настройки перманентными AFAIK нет. [`man XServer`](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R6.8.2/doc/Xserver.1.html) предлагает положить настройки в `/etc/Xn.hosts` (например `X0.host` итд, по одному файлу на каждый запускаемый X-дисплей).

Другим расхожим способом является добавление команды в автозапуск, например в `~/.profile` или `/etc/profile` чего-то вроде этого:

```
[ -n "$DISPLAY" ] && xhost +local:
```